# Populate Sharepoint:AspMenu programatically

Tags: navigation

I wonder if Sharepoint:Aspmenu could be populated programmatically with object model?

Thanks

Comment: can you explain which sharepoint menu your talking about here

Comment: hi, i am talking about the control http://imageshack.us/a/img580/9606/testpaa.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never tried populating it programmatically but you can look at this MSDN [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.aspmenu.aspx) that explains how to use this control behind code, you might have to navigate through to find what you actually want.

**More hints:**

If you want to bind it you can use [DataBind](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/c36y308f) method

Hope it helps :)